# Помогите добавить подзапрос в сравнение

Tags: mysql, sql, opencart

В opencart есть выборка товаров по множеству критериев, но мне нужно добавить еще один по верхнему и нижнему уровню цены, причем в сравнении должны участвовать как цена, так и скидки и акции. По непонятной причине при проверке подзапроса выдает ошибку

> `#1054 - Unknown column 'discount' in 'where clause'`

Понятно что такого в таблице нет, но поле ведь формируется. Подскажите как можно использовать полученное значение discount в условии. (Самое не понятное, что в  ORDER BY не ругается, а в WHERE проблема)

```
SELECT p.product_id
      ,(SELECT price 
        FROM me_oc_ga_product_discount pd2 
        WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id 
              AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1' 
              AND pd2.quantity = '1' 
              AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) 
              AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) 
        ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount 
FROM me_oc_ga_product_to_category p2c 
    LEFT JOIN me_oc_ga_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) 
    LEFT JOIN me_oc_ga_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
    LEFT JOIN me_oc_ga_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id)
WHERE pd.language_id = '2' 
      AND p.status = '1' 
      AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
      AND p2s.store_id = '0' 
      AND p2c.category_id = '96' 
      AND discount IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END) ASC
          , LCASE(pd.name) ASC LIMIT 0,5
```

Comment: К алиасу обратиться в where невозможно. Надо обернуть запрос еще в один `select * from (ваш запрос) A where вот тут можно использовать имена которые были сделаны в запросе`

Answer (score 2):

> Самое не понятное, что в ORDER BY не ругается, а в WHERE проблема

Посмотрите [порядок выполнения предложений SELECT](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_having_clause.html):

```
1: FROM
2: WHERE
3: GROUP BY
4: HAVING
5: SELECT
6: ORDER BY
```

псевдонимы столбцов "появляются" в предложении `SELECT`, т.е. в предложении `WHERE` их просто ещё не существует, а вот в предложении `ORDER BY` их уже можно использовать.

В вашем случае можно добавить дополнительный подзапрос:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM(
    SELECT p.product_id
          ,(SELECT price 
            FROM me_oc_ga_product_discount pd2 
            WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id 
                  AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1' 
                  AND pd2.quantity = '1' 
                  AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) 
                  AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) 
            ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount 
    FROM me_oc_ga_product_to_category p2c 
        INNER JOIN me_oc_ga_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) 
        INNER JOIN me_oc_ga_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id)
        LEFT JOIN me_oc_ga_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
    WHERE pd.language_id = '2' 
          AND p.status = '1' 
          AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
          AND p2s.store_id = '0' 
          AND p2c.category_id = '96' 
    GROUP BY p.product_id 
    ORDER BY (CASE WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END) ASC
              , LCASE(pd.name) ASC LIMIT 0,5
)T
WHERE T.discount IS NOT NULL
```

Попробуйте ещё такой вариант, теоретически может выполняться быстрее, нужно смотреть на конретных данных:

```
SELECT p.product_id
      ,(SELECT price 
        FROM me_oc_ga_product_discount pd2 
        WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id 
              AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1' 
              AND pd2.quantity = '1' 
              AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) 
              AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) 
        ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount 
FROM me_oc_ga_product_to_category p2c 
    INNER JOIN me_oc_ga_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) 
    INNER JOIN me_oc_ga_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id)
    LEFT JOIN me_oc_ga_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
WHERE pd.language_id = '2' 
      AND p.status = '1' 
      AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
      AND p2s.store_id = '0' 
      AND p2c.category_id = '96' 
      AND EXISTS 
       (SELECT price 
        FROM me_oc_ga_product_discount pd2 
        WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id 
              AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1' 
              AND pd2.quantity = '1' 
              AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) 
              AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) 
      )
GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END) ASC
          , LCASE(pd.name) ASC LIMIT 0,5
```

ps: `LEFT JOIN`'s для таблиц `me_oc_ga_product` и `me_oc_ga_product_to_store`  не нужны, так как если там будет `NULL` - столбцы перечисленные в `WHERE` тоже будут `NULL` и такие строки всё равно не попадут в итоговую выборку.

Comment: Я убрал часть запроса там еще две таблицы (так же подзапросами, но он и не имеют особого значения)

Comment: Действительно пришлось добавить подзапрос